# r - condition on list-column dataframe and row number

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a list-column like below:

```
L1 <- data.frame(a = I(list(
  c(1, 2, 6, 7),
  c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7),
  c(2, 3, 5),
  c(4, 5),
  c(4, 5, 7),
  c(6)
)))
```

I need to produce two new columns based on the row number value and the value in the list-column based on the following assumptions:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the `list` column with `map2` and do a comparison with the corresponding `row_number()` to create the two columns

```
library(tidyverse)
 L1 %>% 
   mutate(n = row_number(),
             col1 = map2_int(a, n, ~ as.integer(any((.x - 1) > .y))),
             col2 = map2_int(a, n, ~ as.integer( any((.x - .y) < 0)))) %>%
   select(-n)    
#              a col1 col2
#1   1, 2, 6, 7    1    0
#2 1, 2, 3,....    1    1
#3      2, 3, 5    1    1
#4         4, 5    0    0
#5      4, 5, 7    1    1
#6            6    0    0
```

Comment: none of the numbers in the list in the third row are not equal to 4 and still the suggested code gives a 1

Comment: @adl It is because of the condition I put it different

Comment: so the part `any(.x > .y)` should be `any(.x == .y + 1)`, and the `any(.x < .y)` should be `any(.x == .y - 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could go through it with e.g. sapply.

```
df <- cbind(L1,
  t(
    sapply(seq(nrow(L1)), function(i) {
      cbind(col1 = any((L1$a[[i]] - i) == 1) + 0,
            col2 = any((L1$a[[i]] - i) == -1) + 0)
      })
    )
) 

colnames(df) <- c(colnames(L1), "col1", "col2")

df

             a col1 col2
1   1, 2, 6, 7    1    0
2 1, 2, 3,....    1    1
3      2, 3, 5    0    1
4         4, 5    1    0
5      4, 5, 7    0    1
6            6    0    0
```